# Max/min latitude of map tile map

Tags: google-maps, openstreetmap, mapquest

I'm trying to build a map based on a center point lat/long, the map will always be a fixed size say 1024 by 1024. The user can chance the center point and zoom.

If I populate the map with map tiles from map quest for example, is there someway I can know the max/min latitudes of the map currently being displayed based on the map tiles?

I want to know this so I can accurately project things onto the map.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [OSM Wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Main_Page) has a description of the [Slippy map tilenames](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames) which also covers lon/lat-to-tilenames and tilenames-to-lon/lat.